# regexp_match not working on text string with special characters in google data studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I've been trying to use `REGEXP_MATCH` to create a custom field in Google Data Studio but it's not working as expected.

Example of the data I'm using it on (this is how the data is formatted in the `tags_name` field:

> {construction,po-johnson,po-james}
>
> {construction,po-sandy,po-occonor}

The objective is to check if a certain name exists, then create a new label.

Here's the code I'm trying (*tags_name* is the field name where the original text string exists):

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(tags_name, ".*(johnson?).*") THEN "Marc Johnson"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(tags_name, ".*(occonor?).*") THEN "Sam Occonor"
  ELSE "undefined"
END
```

Is this happening due to the presence of the curly brackets/commas/hyphens?

Comment: In what way is it 'not working as expected'? Are you getting "undefined" with tags_name that should be recognized? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: i'm getting only undefined

Comment: Try `"(?s).*(johnson?).*"` and `"(?s).*(occonor?).*"`

Comment: It would be good to check whether your `tags_name` parameter is fed properly. You can check it by replacing the result in the ELSE close. Instead of `ELSE "undefined"`, try `ELSE CONCAT("The tags_name is: ", tags_name)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried this one but still not picking up any value

Comment: @colourCoder apparently, in data studio *THEN/ELSE statements cannot contain functions or mathematical operations.* (that's what i'm getting when trying to use *concat*

Comment: @johann_s ok, in that case we can try the simplified version `ELSE tags_name`.

Comment: Also, the curly brackets or hyphens are not an issue. (To verify this, you can check any string against your regex on this website: https://regex101.com/. )

Comment: @colourCoder thanks for this. i tried using the `tags_name` and it works (in that it shows the identical `tags_name` value when the `regexp_match` fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the error in Google Data Studio based on your problem statement. Everything worked exactly as expected though.

I've entered your input (and a few other expressions for confirmation) in the `tags_name` field and placed your `REGEXP_MATCH` function into another field:

[image: Screenshot of Data Studio Report with a regex detail]

Here is the result:

[image: Data Studio report table with tags_name column and result column]

Is this the result you expected?

Is there still an issue? If so, you could edit your question and add corresponding screenshots.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to test this. i have been doing some further checks online for similar issues and it seems this is a bug specific to PostgresSQL connections - flagged with Google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141189441)

I've tried using a data extract in google sheets and connected it to datastudio which seems to work (similar to your example)

Comment: gladly :) thank you for the update, good to know what the issue was